# Ms Access Query

Tags: database, ms-access

If there are two tables. Table A has table_code as PK and its FK in Table B.
How can query be designed so that the results display all those values of table_code which is in Table A but not in Table B?

Tried all three joins
Tried Criteria is null and is not null

Comment: can you try this? SELECT tableA.table_code FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.table_code <> table2.table_code

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT tableA.table_code
FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.table_code = tableB.table_code
WHERE (((tableB.table_code) Is Null));
```

if this doesn't help, show us the SQL you tried.